# Fancybox / How to scroll in opened div and have the background fixed?

Tags: facebook, background, scroll, fancybox

I'm currently working on a project with some fancybox (inline content).
I'd like to have the same kind of behavior that exists on facebook: when I click, the content is displayed in the fancybox, and if I scroll, I do scroll in the fancybox, but the background has to remain fixed.

I tried to mix a couple of ideas I've found here and there, mainly:

```
$(".jqShowArticle, .jqShowPortfolio").fancybox({
  'onStart'        : function(){
    $("body").css({"overflow": "hidden", "position": "fixed"});
    $("#fancybox-overlay").css({"overflow": "scroll"});
  },
  'onClosed'        : function(){
    $("body").css({"overflow": "auto", "position": ""});
  }
});
```

But it doesn't work... Here is the page: http://espresso.double-espresso.com/
You can click on every portfolio item (pictures with text appearing on hover...) or blog entry to see what it does...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an answer on https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/24. I'm not sure how they do it exactly though.